# Xubuntu using xfce closes session every time without asking

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crash, xfce, session

My xfce session closes all the time, without any kind of prompt or message box saying that it will close.

The weird thing is that it is almost automatically, I was using VirtualBox without a problem and out of nowhere it closed automatically and it went back to the log in screen. Then I log in using my username/password and the last session gets saved.

Does somebody knows what might be the cause of this? Maybe some preferences? I already checked out the basic ones and nothing seems wrong. Maybe I can set up a hook or something to detect what triggers the log out event, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Same problem for me, XUbuntu virtual machine under VMWare behaving just as you described: sometimes gets me back to login screen without prompting. Sometimes after login it shows me a "crash alert" but no other details. [Edit: Just found an xfce4-session segfault in kern.log, help?]

Comment: Same is happening with me on Mint 14 (Ubuntu 12.04 based). Can't find a solution anywhere. XFCE spontaneously logs out once, sometimes twice every hour.

Comment: When is the last time you updated?

Comment: It still crash on mint 19

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a *crash* than a *close*. What does `~/.xsession-errors` or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (resp. their `*.old` versions) say? @CaNNaDaRk, I'd suggest to report the segfault to the Xubuntu folks...